# Finding Date difference based on the given value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data which looks like below.

```
ID  Date    Currency
1   9/29/2015   INR
1   10/28/2015  INR
1   10/29/2015  INR
1   11/8/2015   EUR
1   11/11/2015  EUR
1   11/23/2015  EUR
1   11/24/2015  EUR
1   11/25/2015  INR
1   11/27/2015  EUR
1   12/1/2015   EUR
1   12/2/2015   CEZ
1   12/3/2015   CEZ
1   12/15/2015  CEZ
1   12/18/2015  INR
1   12/29/2015  INR
```

I want to calculate the difference between the date when the given the currency is same. For example, the first three are of same currency and therefor the difference will be calculated for the date 1 and date 3. Similarly, for rest of the rows I need to calculate. Precisely, the output looks like below.

```
ID  Date    Date2   Currency    Difference
1   9/29/2015   10/29/2015  INR 30
1   11/8/2015   11/24/2015  EUR 16
1   11/25/2015  11/25/2015  INR 0
1   11/27/2015  12/1/2015   EUR 4
1   12/2/2015   12/15/2015  CEZ 13
1   12/18/2015  12/29/2015  INR 11
```

I really appreciate if someone helps me to achieve this using excel

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where you have run into problems, and we will be glad to help you.  This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, how do you define "Date 3"? Will it be the last (i.e. most recent) date, or simply the one that occurs last in your list? It looks like it's chronological, but what if the `date 3` is earlier than `date 2`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Through the research, I tried to create using helper but unfortunately I could not derive the logic to do that which forced me to post the question. Also, the data has been sorted initially by ID and Date and hence it will be on chronological order. So there wont be any chance for the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the three columns are placed in column A, B and C and you start in row 1, then you can append two additional columns.

Cell D2, pull formula down:

```
=IF(C2=C1,D1,B2)
```

Cell E2, pull formula down:

```
=IF(C2=C3,"",B2-D2)
```

Column E now contains the desired result. For convenience, you can place a filter on the table to filter out the empty values in that column.